# índice rmarkdown mapeando sobre un tibble

Tags: r, r-markdown

Mi questión es que **quiero automatizar un índice para un html de rmarkdown.**. Cada apartado quiero que sea una fila de un tibble anidado en el que el el título de la sección sea el nombre de la variable y el contenido sea un gráfico que yo tengo para esa fila, creado con `pmap`. Por poner un ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

test<- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    plots= pmap(
      list(Species,data),
      ~ ..2 %>% 
        ggplot(aes(Petal.Length,Petal.Width )) +
        geom_point()+
        labs(title = ..1)))
```

[image: Esto sería lo que tengo después de obtener los gráficos]

En este caso, quisiera que en el markdown los títulos en el índice fueran la columna "Species" y que el contenido sea la variable plots. He visto soluciones con esto `iwalk`, pero lista de gráficos aisladas y no un tibble en conjunto, donde no puedo aislar los elementos, o por lo menos no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo para este caso. Estoy probando con la librería `purr` los siguiente:

```
pmap(
  list(test1$Species,test1$plots),
  function(.x, .y){
       cat(sprintf("## ", .x ) )
       print(.y)
  })
```

Sin embargo el resultado duplica los gráficos e ignora el el nombre de las variables para el etiquetado. Tampoco me deja otras funcionalidades como ponerle etiquetas a la figuras para referenciarlas en caso de que me hagan falta.

Lo curioso es que con el primer `pmap` si consigo mover los nombres de las variables. ergo debería poder trabajar con ellas para la iteración para conseguir los índices. ¿Cómo puedo **automatizarlos**?

Comment: tampoco parece funcionar ``` x %>%
  set_names(test1$Species) %>%
  iwalk(function(.x,.y){
    cat('# ',.y)
    print(.x)
  })````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Va una solución usando funcionales.

Tres cuestiones importantes por las que no estaba funcionando tu código:

1. En el encabezado del bloque de código (chunk) tienes que indicar que los resultados salen `'asis'`. Con esto le indicas al motor de `rmarkdown` que no debe preformatear la salida y pasarla en crudo a `pandoc`. De ese modo se interpreta como caracteres, se reconocen los `#` y se convierten en títulos o subtítulos.
2. Es necesario agregar saltos de línea `\n` manualmente al `cat`. `cat` es muy elemental y no los agrega por sí mismo. Yo uso `paste` en lugar de `sprintf` porque a este último lo entiendo poco. En principio no debería ser un problema, pero quién sabe.
3. Al armar la lista con `list()` y teniendo ya una lista creas un nivel más de anidado y creo que es por eso que los gráficos se imprimían dos veces. Simplifiqué la manera en que se crea la lista de modo que sea una lista nombrada de objetos `gg`.

El primer bloque de código queda igual. El segundo quedaría así:

````
```{r results = 'asis'}
test1$plots %>%                 #Toma la lista de gráficos "suelta" y no le creo una lista contenedora
  setNames(test1$Species) %>%   #Una lista nombrada es más simple que dos listas
  iwalk(function(.x, .y) {      #Itero sobre lista y nombres
    cat(paste("\n#", .y,"\n"))  #Los \n manuales
    print(.x)                   #De acá sale el gráfico
    cat("\n")                   #Este no sé exactamente por qué hace falta, pero hace falta
  })
```
````

Una solución alternativa usando bucles, para quién prefiere mantener los índices a mano:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  cat(paste("#", test1[[1]][i]),"\n")  
  print(test1[[3]][i])
  cat("\n")
  }
```

Comment: Oh! es cierto, realmente hacen fala un salto de línea al comenzar el nombramiento de la sección para el markdown y otro después del gráfico. Nunca consideré esa opción, pues por algún motivo asumí que no hacía falta (a veces no caemos en los detalles más pequeños o triviales). Ciertamente, iwalk es mucho más eficaz para este caso que pmap. No terminé de entender su uso hasta este ejemplo.

Comment: `imap` e `iwalk` son buenísimas cognitivamente: dirigen tu atención al armado de la lista input y no a la lógica del código que las procesa. De ese modo se te aclara mucho el problema que estás tratando de resolver y encuentras una solución elegante y mantenible. Las adoro.